# how to override model in Magento-2

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

override addressrepository.php for hide last name validation (using plugin)

```
Vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/AddressRepository.php
```

anyone knows explain me

Comment: but i want override addressrepository.php for removing last name validation.if u know that

Comment: You can follow the same flow just change the block class